# Grouping styles by selector or media query first

Tags: css, sass, media-queries

Imagine we have a stylesheet with two classes, a and b, each with styles changing at a certain breakpoint:

```
.a {
  //styles
}

.b {
  //styles
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .a {
      //mobile styles
    }
    .b {
      //mobile styles
    }
}
```

These are grouped by breakpoint. Is it ever preferred to group them by selector instead? i.e:

```
.a {
  //styles
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .a {
    //styles
  }
}

.b {
  //styles
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .b {
    //styles
  }
}
```

The second looks a bit uglier, but that could easily be corrected with [scss nested media queries](https://chipcullen.com/sass-trailing-ampersand-modular-code/). My concern with the former pattern is that it can encourage developers to edit one section of styles without taking a look at how a style change may affect its counterparts at other breakpoints. However, the former may be more useful for developers working on problems that appear only at specific screen sizes.

Would love to hear any thoughts or schools of thought with regard to this conflict of grouping - I've been looking for any resources on Smashing Magazine or CSS tricks but haven't come up with anything.

Comment: If you are using SCSS, it's far better and more manageable to nest the media queries in each selector. It is also advised to use a mobile-first approach, rather than a max-width approach. It's far more concise code that way.

Comment: @SeanStopnik sure - I just threw the "max-width" in as it was the first media query that came to mind. I am inclined to agree that that's the better approach, but I'm not sure that the benefit comes from conciseness - I think that each pattern would generally come down to ~ the same number of lines of code. Is this the pattern you use day-to-day? Are there any other benefits you see? Any drawbacks?

Comment: A mobile-first approach delivers only the style rules to the screen size you are viewing it on, versus delivering ALL the styles to every screen, and then overwriting those styles to fit the desired look. This creates a faster, cleaner experience for the user.

Comment: @SeanStopnik my mistake - I agree with what you're saying with regard to a mobile-first approach. I accidentally worded my sentence "I am inclined to agree that that's the better approach..." in a misleading way. What I meant to ask about was why you believed nesting media queries in each selector was more manageable.

Comment: By nesting the media queries, it makes it far more readable and locatable when troubleshooting or managing a large codebase. Far more organized in the long run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing ample research, I've personally arrived at this answer

1. Keeping the styles for the same selector at different breakpoints *is good* for the developer experience - it keeps CSS more maintainable to be able to see a selector's behavior at every breakpoint all in the same place.
2. In vanilla CSS, the pattern for doing this can be a bit ugly and unwieldy - if it's not minified, it can also lead to some performance issues due to duplicate media queries. **Ruling:** avoid grouping selectors and their media query counterparts in vanilla CSS - it's probably more trouble than it's worth.
3. If you're using SCSS, *absolutely nest your media queries inside your selectors*. It's clean and more maintainable. With the right compilation you avoid duplicate media queries, avoiding the earlier discussed performance issues. [Learn more here](https://storyware.co/writing-maintainable-media-queries-scss/)

Comment: More than happy to mark another answer as correct if someone has something to add to this conversation.